# Finding Determinant efficiently of specific kind of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

$$M=\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}
kI & A & \ldots & A & A\\
A & kI & \ldots & A & A\\
\vdots &  &  & \vdots & \vdots\\
A & A & \ldots & A & kI
\end{array}\right]$$
$M$ is a square matrix
That is, $M$ has the $kI$ matrix along its main diagonal and matrix $A$ elsewhere.
$A$ is a matrix of dimension $n\times n$ having all elements equal,
$kI$ is also an $n\times n$ matrix, the identity matrix multiplied by a constant $k$

How can I find the determinant efficiently of such matrices for small values of $n$?
Can it be done by simple transformations??

Comment: @par yes i am sorry for the bad display

Comment: user77146: Thanks. I deleted my comment by accident but it looks like @Stahl salvaged the LaTeX, so all is well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $M$ is $mn\times mn$. If $A$ is diagonalisable to $D=\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)$, then $M$ is similar to
$$
M_1=\begin{bmatrix}
kI & D & \ldots & D & D\\
D & kI & \ldots & D & D\\
\vdots &  &  & \vdots & \vdots\\
D & D & \ldots & D & kI
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and $M_1$ is permutation-similar to $B_1\oplus\cdots\oplus B_n$, where
$$
B_i=\begin{bmatrix}
k & \lambda_i & \ldots & \lambda_i & \lambda_i\\
\lambda_i & k & \ldots & \lambda_i & \lambda_i\\
\vdots &  &  & \vdots & \vdots\\
\lambda_i & \lambda_i & \ldots & \lambda_i & k
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Hence
$$\det(M)=\prod_{i=1}^n\det(B_i)=\prod_{i=1}^n (k-\lambda_i)^{m-1}(k+(m-1)\lambda_i).\tag{1}$$
Since diagonalisable matrices are dense in the matrix space, formula $(1)$ applies for nondiagonalisable $A$ as well. (I assume that you are working over $\mathbb{C}$. For other fields, that $(1)$ works for nondiagonalisable matrices has to be justified by [other more general reasons](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/313284/why-is-a-matrix-of-indeterminates-diagonalizable).)