# The multiplicative property of cofactor matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, multiplicative-function

In this question, we just consider square matrices.

The cofactor matrix $\mathrm{C}(\mathrm{A}) = (c_{ij})$ of a $n$-by-$n$ matrix $\mathrm{A} = (a_{ij})$ is a $n$-by-$n$ matrix ($n > 0$) with

$$c_{ij} = (-1)^{i+j} \cdot \det{(\mathrm{A}_{ij})} \; \forall i,j,$$

where $\mathrm{A}_{ij}$ is the matrix remaining after removing the $i$-th row and the $j$-th column from $\mathrm{A}$.

**Problem:** Let $\mathrm{A},\mathrm{B}$ be $n$-by-$n$ matrices. Prove that $\mathrm{C}(\mathrm{AB}) = \mathrm{C}(\mathrm{A})\cdot\mathrm{C}(\mathrm{B})$.

I start learning Linear Algebra recently, and this property is one of the problems giving me hard time proving. After giving up, I begin searching for a solution but not succeeding (my effort might not be enough). Therefore, I hope I can find a solution or a link to a solution here, and it's better that this solution uses no linear space and mapping knowledge. For further information about cofactor matrices and its relatives, you can read [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_%28linear_algebra%29) linked.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $C(A)$ be matrix with entries $\alpha_{ij}$, and likewise $B(A)=(\beta_{ij})$.
Then the entries $\gamma_{ij}$ of $C(A)C(B)$ can be written as
$$
\gamma_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_{ik} \beta_{kj} = \sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{i+j+2k} \det(A_{ik}) \det(B_{kj}) = (-1)^{i+j}\sum_{k=1}^n\det(A_{ik}) \det(B_{kj}).
$$
One can check that 
$$
(AB)_{ij} = A_{i\cdot}B_{\cdot j},
$$
where $A_{i\cdot}$ and $B_{\cdot j}$ are submatrices of $A$ and $B$ without the
$i$th row and $j$th columns respectively, $A_{i\cdot}\in\mathbb R^{n-1,n}$, $B_{\cdot j}\in\mathbb R^{n,n-1}$ (or any other field instead of $\mathbb R$).

By the [Cauchy-Binet formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Binet_formula),
$$
\det(A_{i\cdot}B_{\cdot j})= \sum_{k=1}^n\det(A_{ik}) \det(B_{kj}).
$$
This proves
$$
\gamma_{ij} =  (-1)^{i+j}\sum_{k=1}^n\det(A_{ik}) \det(B_{kj}) =(-1)^{i+j}\det((AB)_{ij} ),
$$
hence the entries of $C(AB)$ and $C(A)C(B)$ conincide.

Comment: Thank you. However, I wonder whether the Cauchy-Binet formula - the most important part of your proof - would be easily proved, at least in your specific case.

Comment: There is a proof on the wikipedia page, which can be simpliflied in this case ofc. I am not aware of any more elementary proof.

Comment: I've found a straightforward proof (having the same idea of the proof in the Wikipedia article, I think so) for the Cauchy-Binet formula (in general cases): http://goo.gl/iUOBQM.
P.S: The third equation in the proof is implied (in my thought) from using the Leibnitz formula of determinants.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are just beginning to learn linear algebra, I'm afraid the following proofs are not appropriate. Yet, I'll leave them here for future references.

***Proof 1.*** (Assume you are talking about real or complex matrices.) For any real or complex matrix $X$ and $t\in\mathbb R$, note that $\det(X+tI)$ and the entries of $C(X+tI)$ are polynomials (and hence continuous functions) in $t$. Since every polynomial in $t$ has only finitely many roots, it follows that when $t>0$ is sufficiently small, $X+tI$ is invertible.

Now, from $X^{-1}=\frac1{\det(X)}\operatorname{adj}(X)$ one obtains $C(X) = \det(X)(X^{-1})^T$. Therefore, if $X$ and $Y$ are invertible matrices, we have 
\begin{align}
C(XY)&=\det(XY)((XY)^{-1})^T\\
&=\det(XY)(Y^{-1}X^{-1})^T\\
&=\det(XY)(X^{-1})^T(Y^{-1})^T\\
&=\det(X)\det(Y)(X^{-1})^T(Y^{-1})^T\\
&=C(X)C(Y).
\end{align}
In particular, $C((A+tI)(B+tI))=C(A+tI)C(B+tI)$ when $t>0$ is sufficiently small. Let $t\to0$, the result follows.

The above proof is an example of the so-called *continuity argument*. Often, if some property is known to be preserved in the limit, and we have difficulties in proving the property at a certain point, we may construct a sequence that converges to that point, and prove that the property holds for the sequence instead.

***Proof 2.*** (Assume you are talking about matrices over, say, an integral domain or a field.) As $C(X) = \det(X)(X^{-1})^T$ when $X$ is invertible, it is straightforward to show that the target equality holds for invertible matrices. In particular, the target equality holds when $A,B$ are two matrices whose entries are $2n^2$ different indeterminates $a_{11},a_{12},\ldots,a_{nn},b_{11},b_{12},\ldots,b_{nn}$. Hence the equality also holds when $A$ and $B$ are specialised to any particular values.

One more impressive use of the above technique of considering "generic" matrices is to prove the Cayley-Hamilton theorem (which is usually introduced in the middle of an introductory linear algebra course). See [q313284](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/313284/1551).

Comment: +1 for Proof 1. I do not understand Proof 2: How to proceed from invertible matrices to non-invertible matrices.

Comment: @daw We don't proceed from invertible matrices to noninvertible matrices. *Every* generic matrix is invertible.

Comment: I still don't understand. "The target equality holds when $A,B$ are two matrices whose entries are $2n^2$ different indeterminates $a_{11},…,a_{nn},b_{11},…,b_{nn}$"- it's true but at that point in Proof 2, it has just been proved in the case of which consists of a condition of $f(a_{11},…,a_{nn})f(b_{11},…,b_{nn}) \neq 0$ (the invertible condition). It's also true that the invertible case comprises almost all cases, but it's still not the whole. So how can we proceed from this?

Comment: @VincentJ.Ruan The matrices $A$ and $B$ are always invertible when $a_{11},\ldots,a_{nn},b_{11},\ldots,b_{nn}$ are $2n^2$ *indeterminates*. That is, if $K$ is the underlying field in the original question, then $A$ and $B$ are invertible over the field of fractions of the polynomial ring $K[a_{11},\ldots,a_{nn},b_{11},\ldots,b_{nn}]$. Hence $C(AB)-C(A)C(B)$ is a zero *polynomial*. So, when the $2n^2$ indeterminates are specialised to any values in $K$ (i.e. we perform an evaluation map), we get $C(AB)-C(A)C(B)=0$ for any $A,B$ over $K$.

Comment: As an analogue, suppose $p\in\mathbb R[x]$ satisfies $p(x)(x-1)-(x^2-1)=0$. We want to find prove that $p(a)=a+1$ for every $a\in\mathbb R$. Since $x-1$ is not the zero polynomial, we may divide both sides by $x-1$ to obtain $p(x)=x+1$. Substitute $x=a$, we get $p(a)=a+1$. Note that in the previous argument, (polynomial) division precedes substitution of variable. Had we performed substitution first with $a=1$, we would get $p(1)(0)-(0)=0$ and we cannot divide by zero to obtain the value of $p(1)$.